# Keep Konva Label Size in a group after transform

Tags: canvas, styles, konvajs

I got the following Code To Draw a dragable rectangle with a label to show on mouse over

the issue is i want the label to keep its size after i apply a transformation to the shape (use mouse click to add the transformer)

```
rectangle.on('mouseover', function() {
  if (mode !== 'tr')
    rectangle.add(labelLeft);
  layer.draw();
})
rectangle.on('mouseout', function() {
  labelLeft.remove();
  layer.draw();
})
// add the labels to layer
layer.add(rectangle)
var tr = new Konva.Transformer({
  anchorStroke: 'red',
  anchorFill: 'yellow',
  anchorSize: 5,
  borderStroke: 'green',
  borderDash: [3, 3]
});
// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);
stage.on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
  if (e.target.name() === 'rect') {
    mode = 'tr';
    labelLeft.remove();
    layer.add(tr);
    tr.attachTo(rectangle);
    layer.draw();
  } else {
    mode = '';
    tr.remove();
    console.log(labelLeft)
    layer.draw();
  }
})
```

and here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidian/60nd7vz9/4/) With the current results

Comment: The transformer modifies the scale of the rect. Since the labelLeft is being added to the rect, it naturally picks up the scale applied to the rect by the transformer. Work on a solution that treats the label as a separate shape in the layer. Also, you might want to think about show & hiding labelLeft rather than adding & removing from the canvas - I don't have a specific reason for that except an assumption that it is better performance. You may want to make a show/hide function for handling labelLeft and you can position it relative to the rect in that too.

Comment: great i will give it a try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Konva.Transformer` is changing `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties of the group.

All inner nodes will be affected by that scale (the label too).

The simplest way to avoid such behavior is just to move the label out of the group. For example into the layer.

```js
rectangle.on('mouseover', function() {
  if (mode !== 'tr') {
    layer.add(labelLeft);
    labelLeft.absolutePosition(rectangle.absolutePosition());
    layer.draw();
  }
});
  rectangle.on('dragstart', function() {
       labelLeft.remove();
      layer.draw();
})
rectangle.on('mouseout', function() {
  labelLeft.remove();
  layer.draw();
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/of3ez6xg/